# A question about unramified quadratic extension of number field

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-theory, class-field-theory

Is there any condition over a number field $K$ for an unramified quadratic extension of $K$ to admit an embedding into an unramified cyclic extension of degree 4 of $K$?

Comment: Is this not answered by Hilbert classfield stuff?

Comment: Please use a high-level tag like "nt.number-theory". I added this tag now.

Comment: As Paul Garrett is saying, there is an answer in terms of class field theory: let $\chi$ be the quadratic class group character corresponding to your extension $L/K$, then there is an embedding as you ask if and only if $\chi$ is the square of another character (necessarily of order $4$) of the class group. Is this the type of answer you are looking for?

Comment: i didn't know this result by Hilbert, thank u so much for this information, does this result exist on his book "The Theory  of Algebraic Number Fields "?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ah... perhaps an amplification of my comment and @Aurel's would be useful to you:

First, this kind of thing is not really in Hilbert's "Zahlbericht", because he only treats a sub-class of extensions... which was already a novelty, etc.

But by the 1920's, Takagi and Artin had clarified/proved the reasonable general case of Hilbert's earlier examples, namely, that the Galois group of the maximal unramified *abelian* extension of a number field was naturally isomorphic to the absolute ideal class group of the ring of integers of that number field. This is a little bit more delicate than just the general assertions of classfield theory, since it requires further attention to ramification...

The general theorems of classfield theory are proven many places, but, as far as I know, the subtler versions, about ramification and "Hilbert classfields", are not reliably proven. (E.g., I think Lang's otherwise very useful "Alg No Th" does not actually prove that, though remarks upon it.)

Anyway, the facts are fairly straightforward! :)